# What is the proper way to handle `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` when using the Ninja Multi-Config cmake generator?

Tags: cmake, ninja, multi-configuration

With the cmake generator "Ninja Multi-Config" what is the proper way to handle `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`. For instance, if you do:

```
$ cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../install -G "Ninja Multi-Config" ..
$ cmake --build . --config Release --target install
```

And then afterwards do

```
$ cmake --build . --config Debug --target install
```

will the files in `../install` be overwritten by the `Debug` install? What is the normal way to handle the install location in such cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default they will be overwritten- Ie. with multi-config, the configurations' files install to the same locations.

#### Command-line "manual" approach

If you don't mind having to do this kind of thing manually on the command-line each time you install, you can just use the [`--prefix`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake--install-0) parameter for `cmake --install <...>`.

From the docs for [`CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX.html):

> The `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` may be defined when configuring a build tree to set its installation prefix. Or, when using the [cmake(1)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#install-a-project) command-line tool's [`--install`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-install) mode, one may specify a different prefix using the `--prefix` option.

In that sense, `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` can be seen as a default value set per-generated buildsystem that can be overridden on the commandline.

So you can do something like `cmake --install <build_dir> --config <config> --prefix <install_dir_unique_to_config>`.

#### defaults in CMakeLists.txt approach

See [this CMake mailing thread for various workarounds](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2017-December/066770.html). Summarized here:

You can (with some exceptions- see the docs) use the [`<CONFIG>_POSTFIX` target property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/CONFIG_POSTFIX.html#prop_tgt:%3CCONFIG%3E_POSTFIX) to append a postfix to an output name of a target.

```
set_target_properties(my_target <more targets can be listed here> PROPERTIES
  DEBUG_POSTFIX "-debug"
  RELEASE_POSTFIX "-release"
  # etc.
)
```

Workaround using `install(DESTINATION)` parameters:

```
install(TARGETS ${LIB_NAME}
  CONFIGURATIONS DEBUG
  EXPORT ${LIB_NAME}Config-d
  PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION "include/${LIB_NAME}"
  LIBRARY DESTINATION "bin/${LIB_NAME}/debug/"
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION "lib/${LIB_NAME}/debug"
)

install(TARGETS ${LIB_NAME}
  CONFIGURATIONS RELEASE
  EXPORT ${LIB_NAME}Config
  PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION "include/${LIB_NAME}"
  LIBRARY DESTINATION "bin/${LIB_NAME}/release/"
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION "lib/${LIB_NAME}/release/"
)
```

#### If you're using CMake Presets

You can use the `installDir` property of your configuration presets and the `${presetName}` variable.

---

Note also that CMake 3.29 adds [an environment variable option to set `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/envvar/CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX.html#envvar:CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX).